OTRS 6: TicketCreate operation returns with a "MissingParameter" error
I'm getting data for an OTRS ticket A with OTRS 6's Ticket::TicketSearch operation via a Python requests call. I want to make a new ticket B whose body text is the same as ticket A's body text. I keep getting back the error {'Error': {'ErrorMessage': 'TicketCreate: Ticket parameter is missing or not valid!', 'ErrorCode': 'TicketCreate.MissingParameter'}} when I try to call Ticket::TicketCreate to do this.
I'm trying to call Ticket::TicketCreate (documentation I'm following) for this. From what I can tell the fields below are what OTRS 6 requires for this call. Am I missing something else? The TicketCreate.MissingParameter error seems to suggest I'm either not including something the operation needs or my parameters into Python's requests.get() function are malformed, but I can't think of why the latter would be happening.
urlForAPI = webserviceURL + '/TicketCreate?'
reqHeaders = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
params = {
    'UserLogin': OTRSLogin,     
    'Password': OTRSPassword,
    'Ticket': {
        'Title': 'some title',
        'QueueID': 27,
        'StateID': 3,
        'PriorityID': 3
     },
     'Article': {
        'CommunicationChannel': 'Email',
        'CommunicationChannelID': 1,
        'IsVisibleForCustomer': 1,
        'ArticleSend': 1,
        'From': fromEmail,
        'Subject': 'some title',
        'Body': bodyTicketA,
        'ContentType': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
     }
}
response = requests.get(url=urlForAPI, params=params, headers=reqHeaders)

